# GoLand gives incorrect HTML/JavaScript warnings and indicators

Tags: javascript, html, ide, goland

1. GoLand is telling me that functions are not being used at all when they are being called with `onClick` instead of `onclick`. I realize `onclick` is correct, but it would be nice if it could also recognize `onClick`
2. On line 4 of the below function, GoLand is telling me that my comparison will always be true since I'm comparing `value: boolean` to `"true": string`. However, `value` is not a `boolean` and is actually a `string`, which I found out when I removed the quotes from `true` and that caused my button to stop working.

I loaded up my workspace in VSCode and found that it accepted both `onClick` and `onclick`, and did not complain about `hidden1.value !== "true"`. I love GoLand... how can I make it as smart of VSCode in these respects?

It appears that GoLand infers `value` is a `boolean` because of line 7 (setting `value` with a `boolean`). If I throw `ToString()` on there, the warning goes away, but I'd like to not have to add this... it works fine as-is and a colleague using vscode likely won't add it, therefore I don't want it to cause an issue for me, using GoLand.

This is in an html file that contains javascript directly inside the `<script>` tag. Is there a way to make this operate more like how vscode is seeing things?

My GoLand settings are HTML5, JSX syntax checking on, JS=ECMAScript 6+, TS=Bundled 4.7.4

```
    function pgMpFunc(el1, el2) {
        const hidden1 = document.getElementById(el1);
        const hidden2 = document.getElementById(el2);
        const turnOn = (hidden1.value !== "true");

        setCheckbox(el1, turnOn);
        hidden1.value = turnOn;

        if (turnOn) {
            setCheckbox(el2, !turnOn);
            enableCheckbox(el2, !turnOn);
            hidden2.value = !turnOn;
        } else {
            enableCheckbox(el2, true);
        }
    }
```

[image: with warning]

[image: without warning]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `hidden1.value` *is* a Boolean, once you change it

We can see this because you are creating it from a Boolean expression:

```
    const turnOn = (hidden1.value !== "true"); // Result is ALWAYS boolean

    setCheckbox(el1, turnOn);
    hidden1.value = turnOn; // And this is what you are putting in there
```

A better way to do that Boolean expression is as follows:

```
    const turnOn = ! hidden1.value;
```

#### Goland is correct about the spelling of `onclick`

If your browser is permissive, it *might* accept onClick, but that is not the standard name and some browsers may not accept it.

Generally, many things in HTML are non-case-sensitive, but JS itself is case-sensitive.

Therefore while it *might* work to use random capitalization in the HTML, it is not a good idea, because one day you may forget and do that in the JS, and it will fail and be a difficult bug to resolve.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't quite understand how can I change it from a string to a boolean. It's a string prior to entering this function. If I could just change the type willy nilly like this, wouldn't that imply that comparing these as booleans would not break my button because it would become a string again when needed?

Comment: In Javascript, you can write a value of any type into a variable or property. It doesn't have to be the type that was there before. So yes, you can change the type at will. Reading them, however, does not cause them to automatically change type, unless you use the looser equality tests, == and !=.  But you are using a stricter tests, !==, which doesn't coerce types.